# Show that the set of functions from the positive integers to the set {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9} is uncountable.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

This proof is available online everywhere and there is even a thread on math.stack about it, however, when I first read the question my intuition was to use the same logic as Cantor.  I came up with almost an identical proof.  This is my second week studying college level mathematics so I have no idea if it's right or wrong.  I am almost sure it's wrong, I want to know what's wrong with it though. [the proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87BYh.jpg)

Comment: Your attempt appears to be exactly Cantor's Diagonal argument, just adapted to the current scenario.  I did not bother reading it carefully enough to check for typos, if you correctly phrased things to work for integers rather than just naturals for example, but Cantor's Diagonal argument is a standard approach which is known to be correct.

Comment: @Hyperion that is dangerous to suggest as the usual interpretation of your hint does not lead to a bijection as the mapping might not be injective.  Note that $0.599999\dots = 0.60000\dots$ for instance.  Correctly accounting for this to make the explicit bijection is harder than you make it sound.

Comment: @Hyperion There is no nice bijection. There are, however, nice injections in both directions.

Comment: @Hyperion further, you have ignored that the domain of our functions is all integers, not just the positive natural numbers.  The functions $f(n)=1$ and $g(n)=\begin{cases}1&\text{if }n\geq 1\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$ are distinct but would have both mapped to the same $0.11111\dots$ under your proposed mapping.

Comment: @JMoravitz do you mean me by "Hyperion" ?

Comment: No. There was a comment previously by the user which was deleted suggesting to consider a bijection from your set to $[0,1]$ by mapping an $f$ to $0.f(1)f(2)f(3)...$ which is incorrect as it gives a surjection but not an injection.  It does lead to a correct proof your set is uncountable but not in the way suggested